# Individual P-values in Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic-regression

I ran a logistic regression with like 10 variables (with R) and some of them have high P-values (>0.05). Should we follow the elimination techniques that we follow in multiple linear regression to remove insignificant variables? Or is the method different in logistic regression?

I'm new to this field so please pardon me if this question sounds silly.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean stepwise regression?

Comment: Removing insignificant variables is not normally a good idea, neither in multiple linear regression, see, e.g., here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541374/ols-regression-results-p-values-0-10-how-to-proceed/541378#541378

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may. The same principle applies for both.

Comment: [And the issues with this kind of stepwise-style regression apply, too.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection)

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your time